# Python tests discovery fails with remote.ssh + conda env

Tags: python, testing, pytest, conda, test-discovery

I'm using vcsode on windows with Remote SSH to develop python code hosted on linux.
My python environment is a conda env based on python3.7.
During the test discovery stage, the run_adapter.py script is launched  and fails with the following log:

python /home/scharlois/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.2.64397/pythonFiles/testing_tools/**run_adapter.py** discover pytest -- --rootdir /path/to/my/project -s --cache-clear tests
Test Discovery failed:
Error: ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Open of /home/scharlois/.conda/envs/conda37/share/proj failed

I have no error when I execute the same command in the conda env. on the remote host

Which interpreter is used to run the run_adapter.py script? Is the conda python one ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the python conda interpreter. (displayed modifying the run_adapter script)

I found a workaround: inserting in the script the folowing lines before the main execution:

```
import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"]=""
```